# Can't log to OpenStack with Python OpenStack SDK

Tags: openstack

I try to create a small python app to create/delete instances on a fresh DevStack install. Following the [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/guides/connect.html), I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import openstack
import sys

from openstack import utils

utils.enable_logging(True, stream=sys.stdout)

def create_connection():
    return openstack.connect(
            auth_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0',
            project_name='demo',
            username='demo',
            password='secret',
            region_name='RegionOne',
            app_name='nfvm',
            app_version='1.0',
    )

con = create_connection()
```

Which produce the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nfvm.py", line 22, in <module>
    con = create_connection()
  File "nfvm.py", line 12, in create_connection
    return openstack.connect(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you do `pip freeze | grep openstacksdk` what does it say?

Comment: @eandersson 'openstacksdk==0.13.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I dont know why, but you have to import some Openstack module explicitly:

```
from openstack import connection
```

Then use the following:

```
return connection.Connection(
...
)
```

Comment: It's odd, I tried your original code on openstacksdk 0.13.0 without an issue. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: Yeah, took me some time to figure out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Same problem, same observations. pip freeze | grep openstacksdk
openstacksdk==0.11.4

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have another file in the same directory called `openstack.py`, or a folder with the name `openstack`.

Delete or re-name that file and you should be good to go.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have anything called openstack in my working folder.